# How do I run Prismjs in a Svelte component?

Tags: javascript, svelte, prismjs

I'm simply trying to implement Prismjs into my Svelte project.

I'm loading the CSS in my `<head>` and I'm importing the JS in my Svelte component.

I'm running into a similar issue described here: https://medium.com/get-it-working/get-prismjs-working-in-react-a6d989e59290

Basically, it seems I need to re-run the script after the component has rendered. I'm trying to accomplish this in the same way as it's described in React in the article by running `Prism.highlightAll()` inside of the `onMount` lifecycle.

I was hoping this approach would work, but I'm not getting anywhere. I still have to refresh the page to see the styles take effect. What am I missing here?

Comment: Can you put together a repro?

Answer (score 1):

tldr; this wasn't a Svelte issue. It was an issue with my serializer for Sanity's `blocks-to-html` utility.

Hi @RichHarris! Upon putting together a repo for reproduction, I found prism worked as expected. I was then able to narrow down my issue.

I should have mentioned initially, I'm using Sapper and pulling in content from Sanity. I made a modification to the serializer for Sanity's `block-content-to-html` utility that is converting my portable text to markup. The `<pre>` tag is getting `data-language='HTML'` from Sanity, and the Prism CSS is expecting `class="language-HTML`. I modified my serializer to:

```
code: ({node}) => 
    h(
        "pre", 
        {
            "data-language": node.language, "class": "language-" + node.language
        }, 
        h("code", {}, node.code)
    )
```

Which was working after refreshing. The class attribute was getting added, and the CSS applied. I'm just sort of thumbing through the code as I don't really know how `blocksToHtml` works, but upon changing the object property to `className`, everything is working as expected:

```
code: ({node}) => 
    h(
        "pre", 
        {
            "data-language": node.language, className: "language-" + node.language
        }, 
        h("code", {}, node.code)
    )
```

Thanks for taking a look, Rich! I'm really enjoying Svelte!